# Sectional curvature as a Hamiltonian on the Grassmanization of the tangent bundle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, ergodic-theory

**Edit:**   According to the  comments to the previous version of this  question, I remove my essential  errors in the question. I thank the commenters very much.

Let $M$ be  a n dimensional manifold. For $k<n$, $G_{k}TM$ is the  space of all $k$ dimensional subspace of $T_{x}M, x\in M$.  It  is  a $n+k(n-k)$ dimensional   manifold  and there is  a natural fibre bundle structure $p:G_{k}TM  \to  M$. For what values of $k,n$, there is  a natural  symplectic  structure on $G_{k}TM$?

In particular is $G_{2}TM$ a symplectic manifold when $M$ is  an even dimensional manifold? What about if $M$ has already a  symplectic  structure?

If the answer is yes, assume that $(M,g)$ is  an even dimensional riemannian  manifold with the  Levi-civita connection $\nabla$.

Define $H:G_{2}TM\to \mathbb{R}$  as  follows: $$H(Y_{x})=\text{The  sectional  curvature of  $Y_{x}$}$$
where  $Y_{x}$ is  a  2  dimensional  subspace  of $T_{x}M$.

Are there some  research or  results for a relation between the geometric  properties  of  $(M,g)$  and dynamical properties  of  the  hamiltonian vector  field associated with the above $H$?

In particular, for  what type of riemannian manifold this Hamiltonian vector field has periodic  solution? For what type of Riemannian manifold the flow of this  Hamiltonian is  ergodic?

Assume  that  $\gamma\subset G_{2}TM$  is  a  solution curve to this  hamiltonian vector  field. What is the  geometric  interpretation for $P(\gamma)\subset M$.

The  last  question is  motivated by the following: The geodesic  flow is  a vector  field on $TM$  and  the geometric interpretation for the projection of the solution on $M$ is " length minimizing". Now for this special hamiltonian "sectional  curvature", we search for an appropriate geometric concept in $M$

Comment: I'm afraid that you have a wrong formula for the dimension of $G_2(TM)$.  Its dimension is $n + 2(n-2) = 3n-2$, not $2n(n-2)$, so, in particular, it is odd when $n$ is odd and thus is not symplectic.  Even when $n$ is not odd, there is no natural symplectic structure on this space, so I don't know what you mean by 'Hamiltonian'.  Unless you can construct a symplectic structure on this space, I'm afraid that the rest of your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Its dimension is $3n-4$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Prof. Bryant Thank you for your comment. I am sorry that I was mistaken on the dimension. as you said the dimension is not necessarily even(I multipled the number inplaceof adding up). On the other hand there is  a   [paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5734/66/2/A09/pdf/0025-5734_66_2_A09.pdf) which I could not open it. To be  honnest, according to my error in computation of dimension, I was asking myself whether this space is symplectic. then I search in google and I find that title. Then I thouth to that hamiltonian. So what is the structure of that paper(I cannot open it)

Comment: @RobertBryant I am realy curios that what is the structure of the linked paper.  Moreover, some related question: for what  values of $k$ and $n$ the standard $G(k,n)$ has a natural symplectic form?(without consideration of any manifold $M$).

Comment: According to the above linked paper, what would be  a true version of my main question in this post?

Comment: @BenMcKay:  Thanks for the correction; $3n-4$ it is!  I really must get around to learning arithmetic some day; so many seem to find it useful.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Unfortunately, I don't know what 'linked paper' you mean.  I don't see a link.  Generally, $G(k,n)$ has no symplectic structure that is invariant under $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @RobertBryant   I added a  link in my first comment if you cliqu on word "paper". Any way this is the link http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5734/66/2/A09/pdf/0025-5734_66_2_A09.pdf

Comment: @RobertBryant  Why there is no  a  symplectic  structure invariant under $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: My institution doesn't subscribe to the journal, but apparently the "symplectic form" is a section of $\Lambda^2 U^* \otimes (TM/U)$ where $U$ is the universal subbundle and $TM/U$ the universal quotient bundle. It isn't really a 2-form, not even a vector-bundle valued 2-form, because it only eats pairs of vectors from $U$. So you might not want to call it symplectic.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to check that there is no invariant symplectic form on the Grassmannian, invariant under $SO(n)$. The stabilizer of a point of the Grassmannian is $SO(k) \times SO(n-k)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^k \otimes \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. So you need to work out the weights of $\Lambda^2$ of this and check that there is no invariant element, I think.

Comment: @BenMcKay  My institution is not subscrie, too. How you conclude from the astract of the paper that he  do not consider a usual symplectic 2 form? is not possile that the paper consider n=even?Could you please more explain on the structure which you mentioned?

Comment: @RobertBryant  did you find the link and could you open it?

Comment: @BenMcKay  what about if  $M$ is  already  a  symplectic  manifold  with a two form $\omega$? Is  $P^{*}(\omega)$ a nondegenerate form on $G_{2}TM$?If the  answer is yes, is it interesting to  study the  Hamiltonian "sectional  curvature"? Here P is the  natural projection from $G_{2}TM$ to  $M$.

Comment: The paper you mentioned has a review on MathSciNet, which explains something about the "symplectic form".

Comment: If $M$ is any manifold, and $f \colon X \to M$ any submersion, then the pullback $f^*\omega$ of any differential form vanishes on the fibers $X_m=f^{-1}(m)$ of the submersion, and therefore is degenerate unless $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: @BenMcKay just now I  do not  access mathscinet. Can I ask you to write a  Brief statment? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an answer, other than a general set of comments to explain why there *is* no answer in the form that the OP wants.

First of all, when $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $k$ is an integer satisfying $0<k<n$, there is no symplectic structure on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(V)$, the space of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, that is invariant under the natural action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.  The reason is simple:  If $E\in \mathrm{Gr}_k(V)$ is a $k$-plane, then there a natural isomorphism
$$
T^\ast_E\mathrm{Gr}_k(V) = (V/E)^\ast\otimes E = \mathrm{Hom}(V/E,E)
$$
and the action of the $E$-stabilizing subgroup $P_E = \{ A\in \mathrm{GL}(V)\ \mid\ A(E) = E\ \}$ on this tangent space is the tensor product representation of $\mathrm{GL}(V/E)\times\mathrm{GL}(E)$.  Under this action, we have the irreducible decomposition
$$
\mathsf{\Lambda}^2\bigl((V/E)^\ast\otimes E\bigr)
= \bigl(\mathsf{\Lambda}^2((V/E)^\ast)\otimes \mathsf{S}^2(E)\bigr) \oplus 
\bigl(\mathsf{S}^2((V/E)^\ast)\otimes \mathsf{\Lambda}^2(E)\bigr),
$$
and neither of these two irreducible summands is the trivial representation on a $1$-dimensional vector space.  Thus, there cannot be any $2$-form (whether degenerate or not) on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(V)$ that is invariant under $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

Note, however, that if one fixes a positive definite inner product on $V$ and considers the action of $\mathrm{SO}(V)$ on $\mathrm{Gr}^+_k(V)$, the Grassmannian of oriented $k$-planes in $V$, then this same calculation shows that there *is* a (nondegenerate and closed) $2$-form on $\mathrm{Gr}^+_k(V)$ that is $\mathrm{SO}(V)$-invariant exactly when $k=2$ or $n{-}2$.

This does give a way to define something like a Hamiltonian vector field associated to the sectional curvature of a Riemannian manifold:  If $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, then the *fibers* of the bundle $\pi:\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(TM)\to M$ of oriented $2$-planes are symplectic manifolds in a natural way.  Thus, if $\sigma:\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(TM)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the sectional curvature function, then there is a vector field $X$ on $\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(TM)$ that is tangent to the fibers of $\pi$ and that, *in each fiber* $\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(T_xM)$, is the  Hamiltonian vector field associated to the function $\sigma_x:\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(T_xM)\to\mathbb{R}$.  However, because the vector field $X$ is tangent to the $\pi$-fibers, its integral curves project to points in $M$, so they are not interesting.  The condition that the flow of $X$ be periodic with some fixed period is very restrictive, of course.  For example, in the first interesting dimension, which is $3$, this condition is that the eigenvalues of the Ricci tensor be constant and that one of them have multiplicity $2$.  (If they are all equal, then $X=0$.)  In higher dimensions, the condition is even more restrictive.

Second, the abstract of the article to which the OP linked explicitly says that the author is constructing a *generalized* symplectic form, but then goes on to muddy the waters by referring to it as a 'symplectic form' (without the word 'generalized') in the next sentence.  Of course, this tensor is not anything like a symplectic form in the usual sense, and it cannot be used to define Hamiltonian vector fields or any of the other usual apparatus in symplectic geometry.  In my opinion, it is a disservice to readers to introduce confusing terminology such as this.

In this particular case, it's not hard to figure out what this 'generalized symplectic form' is, since it is supposed to be invariant under the natural action of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ on the bundle $\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$.  It was identified by É. Cartan (though not by that name) more than a century ago, as the canonical torsion associated to the contact system on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$.  One can describe it as follows:  If $\pi:\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)\to M$ is the basepoint mapping (i.e., $\pi(E) = x$ when $E\in\mathrm{Gr}_k(T_xM)$), then there is a canonical subspace (known classically as the *contact system*, as it generalizes the contact plane field in the classical case $k=n{-}1$) $D_E\subset T_E\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$ of codimension $n{-}k$ such that $\pi'(E)(D_E) = E$, and there is also a canonical quotient bundle 
$$
Q =  \bigl(T\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)\bigr)/D,
$$
whose fiber $Q_E$ is naturally isomorphic to $\bigl(T_{\pi(E)}M\bigr)/E$. 
For vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$ that are everywhere tangent to $D$, define a section $\delta(X,Y)$ of $Q$ by the formula 
$$
\delta(X,Y)(E) = \pi'(E)\bigl([X,Y]\bigr) + E \in \bigl(T_{\pi(E)}M\bigr)/E = Q_E.
$$
Then $\delta$, which is clearly bilinear and antisymmetric, is also linear over the smooth functions on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$. Thus, $\delta$ is a section of the bundle $Q\otimes\mathsf{\Lambda}^2(D^\ast)$, and it is invariant under the natural induced (i.e., *prolonged*) action of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ on $\mathrm{Gr}_k(TM)$.  This $\delta$ is what the author of the linked paper calls a 'generalized symplectic form'.  It is not ever a genuine symplectic form, and essentially none of the usual constructions in symplectic geometry apply to it.

Comment: However, what if - as the op suggested - the manifold $(M, g)$ comes already with a symplectic structure $\omega$ (e.g. a Kähler manifold)? Then one could form $\pi^* \omega + \tau$ on $G_2(T M)$, where $\tau$ is the symplectic structure on the fibers. However, this is probably not closed unless $M$ is flat, I did not check this.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig:  Indeed, using the natural way (via the Levi-Civita connection) to extend the fiberwise $\tau$ to a $2$-form on $\mathrm{Gr}^+_2(TM)$, one does *not* get a closed $2$-form unless the metric is flat.